# How to configure the "file://" link handler on Windows to run a specific command?

Tags: windows

How do I configure the app that handles the `file://` protocol in Windows 11?

Currently, if I enter a `file://` URI in the run dialog, or click on one in the terminal, it always opens VS Code.

I've checked under “Apps > Default apps” (VS Code isn't even listed) and “Apps > Default apps > Choose defaults by link type”, but I couldn't find anything related to `file://`. Even though I could find protocols like HTTP, or HTTPS.

Also, I couldn't really figure out, how to "freely" change the handlers.

It always just offers me a list of apps. For example, browsers on the HTTP protocol. I would like to open files with a certain command, e.g. `vim`.

Do the apps need to register a "handler" for it to show up? If yes, can I force it to open using a command?

Comment: Perhaps helpful SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32694642/1256347

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke, thanks, but I'm a bit confused by the linked post. Do I need to write c# code to change how the file protocol is handled? I was hoping not having to hack in the registry, and especially not through code, lol.

Comment: Yes, to be honest, so am I. But I think changing the registry is unavoidable. Perhaps that's a direction you can search in further, using keywords such as URI and registry?